# which of the following JSON is better to work with specially when we have to select data between 2 dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Which of the following JSON format will be better. According to me second will be better as I can directly find the data of particular date just by array index. which should I prefer.

First

```
 [{
  "date" : "20100808", //2010-08-08
  "data" : "one"
 },
 {
  "date" : "20100809",
  "data" : "Two"
 }]
```

Second

```
 [{
  "20100808" : "one"
 },
 {
  "20100809" : "Two"
 }]
```

Comment: In both cases, you will first have to transform the data in such a way that a querying is possible without having to iterate every single item of the original array.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I guess in second case we dont need to iterate right as I can directly get the data of specific date just by using date as index. e.g. objectName["20100808"]. so I dont need to iterate here

Comment: No, you need to go to `objectName[i]["201000808"]` assuming that `objectName` is the entire array.

Comment: I would say neither and would go for a hash structure like `{"20100808" : "one", "20100809" : "Two"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to `select data between two dates`, the first one is better. You can write something like

```
data = [{
  "date" : "20100808", //2010-08-08
  "data" : "one"
 },
 {
  "date" : "20100809",
  "data" : "Two"
}];

dataBetwnTwoDates = data.filter(function(d) {
  var date = new Date(d.date);               // insert your function to convert "20100808" into Date object and store in date.
  return +date > +date1 && +date < date2;    // +date will convert Date object to integer; date1 and date2 are Date objects in between whom you want the data to be.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirement from the title that you want to search for data within a range your first suggestion seems promising. Just to be sure, I'd expect a function signature similar to

```
collect_data(json_arr, begin_date, end_date) {}
```

where the function returns an array of "data" elements as depicted in your JSON snippets.

**Range Queries**

Assuming that the elements of your array are sorted by date you can do a binary search on `begin_date` to find the first element that should fall into the range and then continue to iterate over the array until end of array or `end_date`.

Two things to watch out for:

1. The exact `begin_date` and `end_date` may not be contained in the JSON (yet binary search still works).
2. The range you are querying for may not be contained in the JSON.

Worst case runtime is O(n) which is the best you can do as you must collect data from every element in the worst case.

**Point Queries**

You can either use the above methodology for point queries as well which would run in O(log(n)), or if you have the space create an index structure that maps timestamps to the right index in the array. e.g.:

```
{
    "20100809": 0, //element to be found in json_arr[0]
    "20100810": 1,
}
```

This would run in O(1).

Comment: Thanks a lot @ben. so you suggesting to have an array with direct date as index. I think that will be better and I can query to select the data between date range as well right if data is sorted?

Comment: I suggested something different for range queries. But you can still use a dictionary and do range queries by linearly iterating over all elements (you have to do this as dictionaries are not sorted), which in the worst case is not worse than what I suggested for range queries but it will be slower on average.

Comment: Thank Ben, can you share some example of what you suggested for better understanding please.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm Maybe clears things up.

Comment: Otherwise you may specify what's unclear to you and I'll try to explain.